# should I submit the same sitemap for all the search console accounts?

Tags: seo, google-search-console, sitemap

I'm gonna have 4 properties in my search console for my website as below:

- `http://example.com/`
- `http://www.example.com/`
- `https://example.com/`
- `https://www.example.com/`

The main URl is: `https://example.com/`

Is it ok if I submit the same sitemap of the main URL in other properties?

Answer (score 1):

First you should keep only one version of your domain and redirect the rest on that i would suggest keep the HTTPS www or non-www, otherwise you are spliting page rank between your domains.

After you've picked your main version submit the sitemap there and you are ready to go!

You dont have to submit the sitemap in the rest of domains or even have them on google console if everything redirects to the main (301 redirect).

Comment: Whether you should have a sitemap for the different properties can depend on whether this is a brand new site or an existing site that is migrating from HTTP to HTTPS (or www to non-www or both). But also, this question is specifically asking whether _the same_ sitemap should be submitted to all properties.

Comment: Yes i understand that since you need the old data before migration but in case of sitemap if you migrated and 301 all pages HTTP doesn't need a sitemap, but i probably should include that ty.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a big deal. Google identifies all these properties as one.

Things that you have to consider are:

1. Upload the disavow file for each property and keep eye on the domain name changes and redirects.
2. Upload the sitemap in case you changed your domain name.

Comment: Thanks for your answer,
The main problem is that the http version of the website  has been 302 redirected 4 years ago and since then they haven't changed the search console account. they haven't submitted any updated sitemap since 2012. I also don't know how to mention redirections in site map. That would be so great if you can help me with that.

Comment: If you change the redirect method to 301/moved permanently, it would fix the issue. Please note that Google identifies the HTTP/HTTPS wensites as one website and it doesn't concern you, but it concerns Google.

Comment: 1. What has "the disavow file" got to do with this question? 2. What has changing the domain name got to do with this question?

Comment: @MrWhite I have seen some people made this mistake. They submit another property and redirect their domains but they forget to submit the sitemap and upload the new disavow file to the new property.